# How to use BerkeleyAligner in my own java class?

Tags: java, text, cpu-word, translation, alignment

I'm trying to use the wordalignment in the BerkeleyAligner.jar file from `http://code.google.com/p/berkeleyaligner/` in my own java class. 
I have already added the .jar file into my buildpath.

What parameters does the `edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.CombinedAligner` take?
What does the `edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.CombinedAligner`output?

What i have are 2 input files that are already sentence aligned; i.e. the sentence from line number X from the sourceFile is the same (but in a different language) as the sentence from line number X of the targetFile.

```
import edu.berkeley.*;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wa.mt.Alignment;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wa.mt.SentencePair;
public class TestAlign {

BufferedReader brSrc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("sourceFile"));
BufferedReader brTrg = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("targetFile"));

String currentSrcLine;

while ((currentSrcLine = brSrc.readLine()) !=null) {
    String currentTrgLine = brTrg.readline();
    // Reads into BerkeleyAligner SentencePair format.
    SentencePair src2trg = new SentencePair(sentCounter, params.get("source"),
        Arrays.asList(srcLine.split(" ")), Arrays.asList(trgLine.split(" ")));
    // How do i call the BerkeleyAligner??
    // -What parameters does the CombinedAligner takes?
    // -What does the function/class returns?
    // I assume it returns a list of strings. 
    // Is there a class in BerkeleyAligner to read the output? 
    // Please provide some example, thank you!!
    Alignment output = edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.CombinedAligner
        .something.something(currentSrcLine, currentTrgLine);
    }
}
```

e.g. sourceFile:

```
this is the first line in the textfile.
that is the second line.
foo bar likes to eat bar foo.
```

e.g. targetFile:

```
Dies ist die erste Textzeile in der Datei.
das ist die zweite Zeile.
foo bar gerne bar foo essen.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Actual Answer***

You just wanted to align text (from a target file and a source file), right?

If so, after creating a sentence pair, you did not even need to put them in a `CombinedAligner`.

You could get an Alignment: `(SentencePair, boolean)` from that. The boolean is if you want a tree alignment.

Putting it into the constructor will generate an Alignment automatically!
So simple!

This is where I got the code: http://code.google.com/p/berkeleyaligner/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/berkeley/nlp/wa/mt/Alignment.java

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, I misunderstood your question, and posted an irrelevant response.

However, I downloaded the jar file, found CombinedAligner.class, and [decompiled it](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/java_decompiler/java_decompiler.php).

Here's what I got:

package edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine;

```
import edu.berkeley.nlp.mt.Alignment;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.mt.SentencePair;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.PosteriorAligner;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.WordAligner;
import fig.basic.Fmt;
import fig.basic.ListUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract  class CombinedAligner extends PosteriorAligner {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    WordAligner wa1;
    WordAligner wa2;

    public CombinedAligner (WordAligner, WordAligner)
    public String getName()
    public Alignment alignSentencePair(SentencePair)
    public List alignSentencePairReturnAll(SentencePair)
    public void setThreshold(int)
    abstract Alignment combineAlignments(Alignment, Alignment, SentencePair)

}
```

It seems that the `Alignment` class you're using is `edu.berkeley.nlp.mt.Alignment`.

Anyway, `CombinedAligner` is abstract, so you can't instantiate it. And I don't know what the `.something`'s are, because there is no static method or field.

I think that what you want, however, is `alignSentencePair(SentencePair)`.

To get this, you need to use a subclass of `CombinedAligner`, as `CombinedAligner` is abstract.

So, after poking around the files, I found these subclasses:

```
edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.HardUnion
edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.HardIntersect
edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.SoftUnion
edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.SoftIntersect
```

You can use these instead of `CombinedAligner` and insert your two sentences as a `SentencePair`!

---

After checking, I realized that `WordAligner` is also abstract!

```
package edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment;
```

import edu.berkeley.nlp.mt.Alignment;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.mt.SentencePair;
import fig.basic.LogInfo;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract  class WordAligner implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
protected String modelPrefix;

public WordAligner ()
public abstract String getName()
public void setThreshold(double)
public Alignment alignSentencePair(SentencePair)
public Map alignSentencePairs(List)
public Alignment thresholdAlignment(Alignment, double)
public String getModelPrefix()
public String toString()
```

}

I found a subclass, though:

```
edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.IterWordAligner
```

**Unfortunately, this is still abstract.**

But there's a subclass of `IterWordAligner` that isn't:
    edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.EMWordAligner

However, the constructor is really weird.

```
public EMWordAligner (SentencePairState$Factory, Evaluator, boolean)
```

It uses an INNER CLASS in the CONSTRUCTOR!? That's terrible programming practice.

WAIT...

**I found a word aligner!
http://code.google.com/p/tdx-nlp/source/browse/trunk/pa2/java/src/cs224n/assignments/WordAlignmentTester.java?r=67**

Maybe that helps and you can resolve your problem with it.

Comment: i mean within the IDE, what parameters should the  `edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.CombinedAligner` take?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: it's a mystery now... `WordAlignerHardUnion(WordAligner wa1, WordAligner wa2)` in `WordAlignerHardUnion.java` but i still cannot instantiate `WordAligner wa1`??

Comment: Okay. I'll take a look at it @2er0.

Comment: The subclass `WordAlignerHardUnion` takes `WordAligner` (the abstract class) as its parameters to initialize. Still i can't call any alignment methods without instantiating an `Aligner`.

Comment: Yep, the berkeleyaligner is the "more complex" and complete version of the wordaligner from the assignment... the complete code documentation is in the locked writeup `http://code.google.com/p/tdx-nlp/` and the complete code for wordalignment isn't release. I guess, i've to cut and paste classes from BerkerleyAligner and build my own version. Sigh, a pity that a good software that isn't usuable out of the command line.

Comment: I'm still not giving up, since the command prompt version of the aligner works, maybe i could try to pipe out a terminal command from the java environment then pipe in the outputs into the IDE. Somewhat like `sysout()` from python codes.